# From beginner, extend coverage with router or extenders?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, home-networking

I'm a network novice, so please bear with me.

I want to extend internet coverage throughout the apartment, and I have no idea how to do it.

Our apartment looks more or less like the image below. The issue is that the concrete walls are thick at about 1', and there's a block of concrete (marked concrete) that's about 6x2 feet. The red indicates the electric outlets.

I was thinking of buying several wifi boosters and even a router, but I'd be buying without knowing.

So any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solutions I can think of:

1. Move the modem/router to a more central location.  I expect this isn't an option and that's why its in the location its in.  So....
2. Wifi extenders.  Wifi Access points.  Or an old, but compatible, wifi router to bridge the connection.  Little more complicated, but better than...
3. Powerline adapters.  Yeah, just stay away from these.
4. Lastly, run cable.

As Yorik says, "It would probably be cheaper and more useful to install a 50' cable along the baseboard(s) that runs around the concrete over next to the first computer. Disable wifi on the modem.router combo and install an inexpensive WIFI router configured as an access point. (option 2 above). All of your primary use-case for wifi is in that corner, the wifi radio ought be there a well."

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Considering the layout of the apartment, how many wifi extenders should I buy?

Comment: You could try just one out and see if it gives you what you want.  I'd probably put it along that left side so that it can "see" the signal and then beam it out to everyone else.  I've never really used one myself.

Comment: It would probably be cheaper and more useful to install a 50' cable along the baseboard(s) that runs around the concrete over next to the first computer. Disable wifi on the modem.router combo and install an inexpensive WIFI router configured as an access point. (option 2 above). All of your primary use-case for wifi is in that corner, the wifi radio ought be there a well.

Comment: @Yorik Can I hijack your comment and add it to my answer?

Comment: Of course: just trying to expand on your information rather than add my own answer.